# using ngOptions with object where keys are arrays and to group by keys

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework, ng-options

I have an object in which the values of keys are arrays: For example:

```
{
    key1 : [item1, item2, item3],
    key2 : [item4, item5, item6]
}
```

I want to display all the 'items' in select box and group them by 'keys'

How can can I do this with ng-options? I read the docs but can't seem to figure out how to do that.

Comment: This is not possible with ngOptions as it is meant to group with a property of the objects it is going through.

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1 (ngRepeat)

Assuming `item1`, `item2`, etc. are objects:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/mhN61HRU1OIeZWpIYHj9?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.rawItems = {
    key1 : [{name: 'item1'}, {name: 'item2'}, {name: 'item3'}],
    key2 : [{name: 'item4'}, {name: 'item5'}, {name: 'item6'}]
  };

});
```

```html
<select
  ng-model="selectedItem"
  class="form-control"
>
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup ng-repeat="(groupName, items) in rawItems" label="{{groupName}}">
    <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.name}}" ng-bind="item.name"></option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

### Option 2 (ngOptions)

You'll first need to transform your array inside controller.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYmbQ08CjbIPsLCkAT5G?p=preview)</kbd>

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  var rawItems = {
    key1 : [{name: 'item1'}, {name: 'item2'}, {name: 'item3'}],
    key2 : [{name: 'item4'}, {name: 'item5'}, {name: 'item6'}]
  };

  $scope.groupedItems = [];
  var option;
  angular.forEach(rawItems, function(items, key){
    option = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(item){
      item.group = key;
      $scope.groupedItems.push(item);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<select
  ng-model="selectedGroupedOption"
  ng-options="value.name as value.name group by value.group for value in groupedItems"
>
  <option>--</option>
</select>
```